# Is there a limit to the types of thrown improvised weapons usable without penalty with Throw Anything?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, improvised-weaponry

So, my character has [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final) by default from [her class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/flaming-crab-games---rogue-archetypes/bomber) and can throw improvised weapons without penalty.

According to [the rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Improvised-Weapons), the damage and size category of an improvised weapon is determined by which actual weapon is the closest to it (ex : a meat cleaver is close to a  Medium handaxe or a Small battleaxe), except that improvised weapons all have a critical threat range of 20 and a critical damage multiplier of x2.

There is one thing I don't get : Does Throw Anything allow to throw really anything (even weapons not designed for throwing and weapons the character is not proficient with) without penalty, or are there exceptions that still impose a -4 penalty to attack rolls for non-proficiency ?

Answer (score 1):

## A creature possessing the feat [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final) can throw only *improvised* weapons without penalty

The benefit of the feat [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final) is that a creature possessing it doesn't "suffer any penalties for using an improvised ranged weapon." Its misleading name to the contrary, the creature can neither make attacks without penalty with *weapons* not designed for throwing nor can the creature make attacks without penalty with  *weapons* with which he's not proficient, as in both cases these are not *improvised weapons* but objects crafted to be weapons.

[Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) on Improvised Weapons says

> **Sometimes objects not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in combat.** Because such objects are not designed for this use, any creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with that object. To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match. An improvised weapon scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

Emphasis mine. For example, a generous GM may allow a creature that possesses the feat Throw Anything to make an attack with no penalty on the attack roll with a playing card as if the playing card were a [shuriken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-thrown-shuriken) yet modified by the improvised weapons rules, but such a creature could *not* make attacks with an actual, for-reals shuriken without suffering a –4 penalty unless the creature were, in fact, proficient with the shuriken, despite possessing the feat Throw Anything.

This jibes with the rules-as-written answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62915/throwing-a-weapon-as-an-improvised-weapon/62961#62961) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26556/8610).

You can read about how folks on the Paizo messageboards agree that the feat Throw Anything is unusual in threads from [2010](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l9oo?Throw-Anything-Throwing-Weapons-not-intended), [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mobc?Quick-Throw-Anything-Clarification#1), [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mtx0?Throw-Anything#1), [2012](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p07n?Does-Throw-Anything-allow-Exotic-Weapons-to), and [2015](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2s7dp?Throw-Anything-is-weird).

### On throwing swords and other weapons

The GM may make a reasonable house rule that allows a creature that possesses the feat Throw Anything to throw, literally, *anything*—including objects crafted to be weapons—with the understanding that such weapons are being misused (i.e. improvised) to a degree that the GM can change the weapon's printed statistics as the GM sees fit (such change the damage the weapon deals or the kind of damage the weapon deals) while having such weapons keep the improvised weapon's 10-ft. range increment and threat range/critical multiplier of 20/×2. Similarly, the GM may rule that a creature that possesses the feat Throw Anything and that throws as an improvised weapon, for example, a [longsword](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longsword) may opt not to suffer the –4 penalty on the attack roll but lose the benefits of longsword-specific feats and special abilities he might also possess (such as the feat [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat---final) (longsword) or the fighter special ability [weapon training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Weapon-Training-Ex-) (heavy blades)). The longsword's *not* being thrown *as* a longsword, after all, but as an improvised weapon.

As an aside, making a ranged attack by *throwing* a melee weapon that does *not* have a listed range increment does *not* make the weapon into an *improvised* ranged weapon—the weapon remains an object crafted to be a weapon—, even though [Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) on Melee and Ranged Weapons says that doing so causes the thrower to suffer

> a –4 penalty on the attack roll. Throwing a light or one-handed weapon is a standard action, while throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action. Regardless of the type of weapon, such an attack scores a threat only on a natural 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. Such a weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

…Which, for example, makes a thrown sword *sound* a lot like an improvised weapon, yet the above rules don't mention improvised weapons at all.

Creative director James Jacobs says in a [2012 Paizo messageboard post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=454?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#22690) that he doesn't like allowing weapons to be used as improvised weapons, and he'd probably say *No* were he GMing a a Pathfinder Society adventure in which a character wanted to try wielding a weapon as an improvised weapon (and wasn't a [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk) with the archetype [monk of the empty hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/monk-of-the-empty-hand)).

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, throw anything allows you to throw any weapon (and even non-weapons) without penalty.

From the Throne Weapons category:

> It is possible to throw a weapon that isn't designed to be thrown, and a character who does so takes a –4 penalty on the attack roll. Throwing a light or one-handed weapon is a standard action, while throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action. Regardless of the type of weapon, such an attack scores a threat only on a natural 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. Such a weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

This is described exactly as an improvised weapon is. It is in fact an improvised ranged weapon, which is exactly what the feat Throw Anything allows you to use without penalty.

The only difference between a true improvised weapon and a weapon being used in a non-standard way is that the damage is already set. So throwing a medium long sword still does 1d8 damage on a hit.